# Is it possible to update a user's cart programatically, knowing only the user ID?

Tags: woocommerce

I am building a subscription service that will add certain items to a user's cart automatically once per week, without their needing to log in. The problem is that WooCommerce seems to carry cart data in multiple spots, and I'm not sure which can serve as a "master" cart that will take precedence. The persistent cart held in user meta appears to be subservient to session cart data. However, I cannot figure out how to get/set session cart data without actually logging in as the user through a browser.

Should I try to somehow spoof a user login to get access to session variables? Or is there a way to do this directly through the WooCommerce API?

Comment: Why not use [WooCommerce Subscriptions](http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/)?

Comment: I actually am using that. I'm trying to also trigger some cart updates based on its hooks. The plugin bypasses the cart entirely by creating orders directly. I would like customers to have an option to change their orders before they go through automatically, though.

Comment: I´m pretty sure that Subscriptions does not bypass the cart at all. There may be a setting that automatically redirects to checkout, which you can disable, but the item is still added to the cart. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm talking about for the automated renewal payments, which don't require the user to be on the site. It happens in the background. I did find a workaround on this and will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out that session data is stored as a site option in the options meta, and if I set both the persistent cart AND the session to the same thing, then it will always load the proper information. Here's a snippet that shows how to do this with serialization:

```
function add_products_programmatically($user_id) {

    // Get the current session data and saved cart
    $wc_session_data = get_option('_wc_session_'.$user_id);

    // Get the persistent cart
    $full_user_meta = get_user_meta($user_id,'_woocommerce_persistent_cart', true);

    // Create a new WC_Cart instance and add products programmatically
    $cart = get_new_cart_with_products();

    // If there is a current session cart, overwrite it with the new cart
    if($wc_session_data) {
        $wc_session_data['cart'] = serialize($cart->cart_contents);
        update_option('_wc_session_'.$user_id, $wc_session_data);
    }

    // Overwrite the persistent cart with the new cart data
    $full_user_meta['cart'] = $cart->cart_contents;
    update_user_meta($user_id, '_woocommerce_persistent_cart', $full_user_meta);
}
```

The get_new_cart_with_products() function is just creating a new WC_Cart() object and adding items, then returning the cart object.